# OpenAM agent redirects to default login url

Tags: openam

I'm trying to install `OpenAM 12.0.2` using Quick Start Guide. Everything works fine, except redirecting unauthenticated user to `OpenAM` login page. In Agent config login URL is set as

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0] = http://www.example.com:8080/openam/UI/Login
```

but user is redirected to

```
http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/UI/Login
```

Seems that any changes to com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0] are not applied.

Any ideas?

- OpenAM 12.0.2
- Web Agent 4.0.0 for Apache 2.2
- OS CentOS 6.7

Comment: Where did you configure the login URL, AgentConfig file or central Agent profile?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved. Incorrect login URL was set in Agent profile. Be carefull during configuration.